# Two webservers and two domains

Tags: php, apache, webserver, ports

On my network, I have two Apache webservers. One running on a Windwos 10 machine with XAMPP, and the second one running on a Raspberry Pi using Raspbian. Both of them are public, and the ports are open. The XAMPP server is using port 80, and the Raspberry is port 81.

I currently have two domains, which in this case I will refer to domain A and domain B. Domain A is meant for the XAMPP server, and domain B is meant for the Raspberry server. To access the XAMPP server I simply use domainA.com, but to access the Raspberry server I have to use domainA.com:81.

So my question is, how do I use my domain B to refer to the Raspberry server with simply using http://domainB.com?

Comment: One note on your tags: you won't be able to fix this via DNS.

Comment: Just change the port on the Pi's webserver from 81 to 80. Why is it running on 81 now?

Comment: This can't be done as you are using http it will assume port 80 for default. If you want to use any other port you should explicitly specify it, which you are doing.

Comment: If I change the port on the Pi to 80, how can I make domain B refer to the Pi then? My question is if it is possible to have two seperate webservers with each domain on same network.

Comment: DomainA should point on an IP, and DomainB on a different one, no ? 
I'm not sure I truely understand your problem, can you be more explicit ?

Comment: DomainA and DomainB point to the same external IP, but I want DomainA to point to the XAMPP server (192.168.1.101), and the DomainB to the Pi server (192.168.1.126)

Comment: The fact that you're not using public IP is pretty important here. See deceze's answer, you have all you need there to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a central NAT device with a single IP address which forwards the ports, then there's no way to do this the way you expect to. You want to differentiate machines by the HTTP Host header, but the NAT is operating a few levels down the [OSI stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) at the IP and port layer and doesn't know anything about HTTP. You will need to have an HTTP capable device (a web server) which accepts requests for both domains and [reverse proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) them to the appropriate server. You could set up one of your two web server to proxy requests for the other web server, or you add a third load balancer/proxy in front of both.